Clash between crop and pagecolor affecting includepdf
My document needs crop marks. The first page has text and a background colour set by \pagecolor, which works fine. Then \pagecolor is used to set the background back to white (as in the MWE). However, \pagecolor stops \includepdf from working (as in the MWE). This is because crop redefines \pagecolor "to only color the logical page".  Note that, unlike the MWE, the packages are all in a class file proprietary to the publisher, so any solution may need to be implemented in the class file.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{crop}
\pdfminorversion=7 
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{somepdf.pdf} % Appears
\pagecolor{white}
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{somepdf.pdf} % MIA
\end{document}


Package crop.sty redefines macro \set@page@color. You can undo this by adding the following before loading crop.sty:
\makeatletter
\let\org@set@page@color\set@page@color
\AtBeginDocument{\let\set@page@color\org@set@page@color}
\makeatother


That works nicely in the MWE, but when I add that code to the class file,  I get this: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Look for typos. Any missing closing braces?

I copied your four lines of code directly into the class file immediately before the crop, and the compile then produced 7 errors, starting with "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}."
I looked at some of the other errors and saw that they relate to lines with @ symbols, so on a hunch I moved the 4 lines and the crop to the end of the CLS file. It didn't work, but I didn't get any errors either. There's another post here with a similar query but a slightly different solution, and that worked  when  implemented at the end of the class file.

So, I have a solution but don't know why it works.

If you put the code in your own class file, then do not use \makeatother which disables the special treatment of the @ character. And \makeatletter is redundant, so remove it too.
